# Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo Laptop (no Nvidia) detects new screen but "no signal"

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, lenovo, display-resolution

Already tried couple fixes I found online, but noting worked yet. :(

Setup:

- Lenovo L15 Laptop Gen3 - 1920x1080px 60Hz
- AOC Q3279VWFD8 monitor - 2560x1440px 75Hz
- HDMI cabel (not broken, works on my PC)

Tried in settings -> display to give the AOC the same resolution and refresh rate, which didn't work.

The strangest thing is, that I tried it for couple of days around 20x times, and ONE TIME IT ACTUALLY WORKED. Since then, never again. Tried "reverse-engineering" plug laptop-first, screen-first, turned the cable, connect in sleep mode, screen-on/off when plugged, nothing.

My laptop doesn't have Nvidia graphic card, so all these Nvidia fixes online don't work for me.

Here's my xrandr terminal result:

```
    ~$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x23) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
    Identifier: 0x21
    Timestamp:  1686368
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x23) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
  1440x1080 (0x24) 129.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1528 end 1680 total 1920 skew    0 clock  67.19KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1087 total 1120           clock  59.99Hz
  1400x1050 (0x25) 121.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1632 total 1864 skew    0 clock  65.32KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1089           clock  59.98Hz
  1280x1024 (0x26) 109.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.67KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x960 (0x27) 101.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1488 total 1696 skew    0 clock  59.70KHz
        v: height  960 start  963 end  967 total  996           clock  59.94Hz
  1152x864 (0x28) 81.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.78KHz
        v: height  864 start  867 end  871 total  897           clock  59.96Hz
  1024x768 (0x29) 63.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock  47.82KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  798           clock  59.92Hz
  800x600 (0x2a) 38.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  832 end  912 total 1024 skew    0 clock  37.35KHz
        v: height  600 start  603 end  607 total  624           clock  59.86Hz
  640x480 (0x2b) 23.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  29.69KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  487 total  500           clock  59.38Hz
  320x240 (0x2c)  6.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   320 start  336 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  15.00KHz
        v: height  240 start  243 end  247 total  252           clock  59.52Hz
  1680x1050 (0x2d) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1440x900 (0x2e) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1528 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x800 (0x2f) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  720x480 (0x30) 26.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  29.85KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  493 total  500           clock  59.71Hz
  640x400 (0x31) 20.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  25.00KHz
        v: height  400 start  403 end  409 total  417           clock  59.95Hz
  320x200 (0x32)  5.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   320 start  336 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  12.50KHz
        v: height  200 start  203 end  209 total  212           clock  58.96Hz
  1600x900 (0x33) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
  1368x768 (0x34) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x720 (0x35) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1024x576 (0x36) 46.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1160 total 1296 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  599           clock  59.90Hz
  864x486 (0x37) 32.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   864 start  888 end  968 total 1072 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  506           clock  59.92Hz
  720x400 (0x38) 22.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  24.83KHz
        v: height  400 start  403 end  413 total  417           clock  59.55Hz
  640x350 (0x39) 17.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  21.88KHz
        v: height  350 start  353 end  363 total  366           clock  59.77Hz
XWAYLAND14 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+0 (0x580) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 730mm x 430mm
    Identifier: 0x5a2
    Timestamp:  1686368
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  2560x1440 (0x580) 397.000MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  2560 start 2760 end 3040 total 3520 skew    0 clock 112.78KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1506           clock  74.89Hz
  1920x1440 (0x581) 297.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2072 end 2280 total 2640 skew    0 clock 112.78KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1447 total 1506           clock  74.89Hz
  1600x1200 (0x582) 204.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1720 end 1888 total 2176 skew    0 clock  93.98KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1207 total 1255           clock  74.88Hz
  1440x1080 (0x583) 165.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1544 end 1696 total 1952 skew    0 clock  84.66KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1087 total 1130           clock  74.92Hz
  1400x1050 (0x584) 156.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1504 end 1648 total 1896 skew    0 clock  82.28KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1099           clock  74.87Hz
  1280x1024 (0x585) 138.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1504 total 1728 skew    0 clock  80.30KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1072           clock  74.90Hz
  1280x960 (0x586) 130.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1504 total 1728 skew    0 clock  75.23KHz
        v: height  960 start  963 end  967 total 1005           clock  74.86Hz
  1152x864 (0x587) 104.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1224 end 1344 total 1536 skew    0 clock  67.71KHz
        v: height  864 start  867 end  871 total  905           clock  74.82Hz
  1024x768 (0x588) 81.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1088 end 1192 total 1360 skew    0 clock  60.11KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  805           clock  74.67Hz
  800x600 (0x575) 49.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  920 total 1040 skew    0 clock  47.12KHz
        v: height  600 start  603 end  607 total  629           clock  74.91Hz
  640x480 (0x576) 30.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  728 total  816 skew    0 clock  37.68KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  487 total  504           clock  74.77Hz
  320x240 (0x577)  7.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   320 start  336 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  18.75KHz
        v: height  240 start  243 end  247 total  254           clock  73.82Hz
  1920x1200 (0x589) 245.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2064 end 2264 total 2608 skew    0 clock  94.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1255           clock  74.93Hz
  1680x1050 (0x58a) 187.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1800 end 1976 total 2272 skew    0 clock  82.31KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1099           clock  74.89Hz
  1440x900 (0x58b) 136.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1536 end 1688 total 1936 skew    0 clock  70.51KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  942           clock  74.85Hz
  1280x800 (0x58c) 106.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1488 total 1696 skew    0 clock  62.65KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  838           clock  74.76Hz
  720x480 (0x578) 34.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  752 end  816 total  912 skew    0 clock  37.55KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  493 total  504           clock  74.51Hz
  640x400 (0x579) 25.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  400 start  403 end  409 total  421           clock  74.23Hz
  320x200 (0x57a)  6.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   320 start  336 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  15.62KHz
        v: height  200 start  203 end  209 total  212           clock  73.70Hz
  2048x1152 (0x58d) 251.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2048 start 2200 end 2416 total 2784 skew    0 clock  90.25KHz
        v: height 1152 start 1155 end 1160 total 1205           clock  74.89Hz
  1920x1080 (0x58e) 220.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2064 end 2264 total 2608 skew    0 clock  84.64KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1130           clock  74.91Hz
  1600x900 (0x58f) 151.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1704 end 1872 total 2144 skew    0 clock  70.55KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  942           clock  74.89Hz
  1368x768 (0x590) 109.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1448 end 1592 total 1816 skew    0 clock  60.16KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  805           clock  74.73Hz
  1280x720 (0x591) 95.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1488 total 1696 skew    0 clock  56.46KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  755           clock  74.78Hz
  1024x576 (0x57b) 60.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock  45.18KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  604           clock  74.80Hz
  864x486 (0x57c) 42.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   864 start  904 end  984 total 1104 skew    0 clock  38.04KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  511           clock  74.45Hz
  720x400 (0x592) 28.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  400 start  403 end  413 total  421           clock  74.23Hz
  640x350 (0x57e) 22.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  27.50KHz
        v: height  350 start  353 end  363 total  369           clock  74.53Hz
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been a frequent issue for Lenovo Laptops lately. Some have had to disable UEFI and boot legacy, others have had to update their BIOS. Looking at their troubleshooting for that model it says you have to press Fn + f7 or Win + P to activate it.
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t15p-gen-3-type-21da-21db/troubleshoot

If you've already done that key combo I would suggest checking your BIOS version and maybe trying to boot without UEFI to see if it makes any difference.
I've had issues with an old dell laptop and wifi, and for that I had to blacklist dell_laptop, so sometimes it is the BIOS.
Hope that helps or someone else has suggestions.

Comment: Thank you so much! For updating BIOS I have downloaded a zip from Lenovo (v.1.20) with two .cab files inside, but have no idea how to install them. Also tried Fn + F7 opens a popup, if I want to activate Caret Browsing. Win + P doesn't have any reaction. Also tried to find out how to disable UEFI, but don't understand it either. I will keep trying but I dont know what I'm doing actually.

Comment: There is a readme on how to update https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n3eul08w.txt that says for Ubuntu:
Manual Update Using fwupdmgr

Comment: updated the BIOS to ```R1XET42W (1.24 )```, still the same problem :(